# Hyperlinks without file://... with openpyxl to open a ws from the same wb?

Tags: hyperlink, openpyxl

I want open ws2 inside the same libreoffice wb with a hyperlink in a cell on ws1.
My code is:

```
wb["test"].cell(row = 1, column = 2).hyperlink = '#%s' % "test2"
```

This works, but `openpyxl` adds *file://...* to the link and a new instance of libreoffice starts (and auto close) with every click on my hyperlink.

If i add manually a hyperlink to libreoffice calc no  *file://* is added and no other instances of libreoffice starts.

**What target_modes are supported?**

I believe `target_mode = "External` is hard coded inside the openpyxl cell hyperlink attr. `wb.cell()._hyperlink_rel.target_mode = "External`

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openpyxl-users/92JFYZEnyE8 ?

Comment: Have you tried:  wb.cell()._hyperlink_rel.target_mode = "Internal" (after setting the hyperlink)?

Comment: @EricLevieil please don't suggest using a private API

Comment: @CharlieClark: I know you shouldn't do that when there is a public API and that even if it happens to work, it's a hack. But in this case, it may fix OP's problem.

Comment: Well, the implementation has since changed.

Answer (score 0):

It's fair to say that support for hyperlinks isn't perfect. However, starting with version 2.3 there is at least full support for the type. The relevant code for serialising could easily be adapted to reflect this.

Comment: Are you saying it would perhaps be added in a future version?

Comment: Sure. Read/write support for hyperlinks should now be fairly straightforward if someone wanted to make a PR. Otherwise it's currently not a priority.